# The things that makes a good beer be a great beer

Tags: flavor

Well, after living in Germany for a couple of months, i understood that the flavor is everything.
Usually people say that a great Beer should be cold, well, i think that's not the main issue. In your opinion what are the things that makes a good Beer? 
Can you name your favorite? So we can have like a List of Great Beers to taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Great Beer is an opinion. Sure, you can look at [RateBeer](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/top-50/) or [BeerAdvocate](http://www.beeradvocate.com/lists/top/) and see the best beers according to votes, but does that really make it the best beer?

A Budweiser can be the best beer in the world on a warm Saturday, but it will not score highly when you are sipping it whilst lying next to a large fire on a cold night.

A Westvleteren 8 is a phenomenal beer, but I would not like it, served at 4C on a hot day.

Your own likes will affect if a beer is great. If you do not like sour beers, then a beer like Cantillon Gueze might be a horrible beer for you, but others will rate it as one of the best beers in the world.

Answer (score 1):

My favourate Beer of all time is: **Sublime Chaos** by *Anarchy Brewery*
[image: Sublime Chaos]

I would say that This is my favorite beer for a few reason

1. Rich Coffee Flavoring
2. Not to heavy (for a stout)
3. Smells amazing

I think when it comes down to the perfect beer it all comes down to an individuals preference some like a nice golden beer some like a wheat beer I personally love a stout or a porter

For me tho a good beer is one that taste amazing, smells amazing and is a pleasure to drink not just drinking for drinking sake it has to be a beer you have a good time drinking